# What are chances that computer (program) made a mistake? like not evaluate if(true)

Tags: errors

*(Probably my question is somehow similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923413/how-often-do-computers-make-mistakes), but I'm interested from the point of program engineers.)*

What are chances and under what circumstances, a computer program could ever made a mistake itself? Like the program didn't evaluate `true` conditions:

```
if(true)
{
    ...
}
```

I assume that a hardware issue in `CPU` might make that, but are there any other chances, beside the hardware failure?

Comment: This sounds like a highly hypothetical question to me, i.e. not the ones Stack Exchange is designed for.

Comment: I'd say the answer is going to be very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20923516/2883328 unless you are looking for something else? ...

Comment: I am thinking possibly errors in the compiler or interpreter might cause such an error.  Chances of that though are probably very small, but nevertheless, commonplace (bugs happen all the time) but they are fixed.

Comment: Unless you are programming a computer that is embedded in a person and keeping them alive, or is controlling a spacecraft or aircraft, or is inside a steel mill's furnace, or something of that sort, then you don't need to think about errors of that sort.

Comment: @whatsisname your answer was the best i think :) and in case of those occasion what those programmers should expect for this question ? ::: )

Comment: @T.Todua: for them, you have a huge excel spreedsheet with your hazard analysis where you go over each and every thing that could go wrong and how those hazards are mitigated, and the details of that process are way too broad for discussion here.

Comment: If a CPU doesn't execute the instructions in the program correctly, that's a hardware failure. End of story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, computers rarely make "mistakes", however programmers...

In this case the program is likely a compiler or interpreter. These are usually *very* well vetted and are rarely wrong for such simple operations. If you have one of the standard ones this is realistically not a risk.

What about the computer actually making a mistake:

In this case very low, any decent compiler would remove the if statement altogether, however for things that need evaluating/storing etc, errors do occur. This is mostly due to 'bit-flipping' which occurs as a result of non-accounted for analog phenomena. These could be as a result of cosmic rays or other EM interference. It's noteworthy that sometimes this can be controlled by an attacker (i.e. row-hammer) by carefully ordering ram operations where the data is stored.
However all of these things are *extremely* rare, unless you are doing something silly like putting your hardware in an spacecraft...

Comment: I like computers.  They execute my mistakes perfectly, every time.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? perfectly valid and interesting answer?

Comment: @DirkBoer this is SE. Can't answer otherwise, there are downvoter brigades out there.